# Vuetify dialog set prop mutation from child to parent

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I'm currently opening a dialog component using this

**Parent**

```
<v-btn color="#EF5350" dark small absolute top right fab 
 @click="showDialog">

   <v-icon>zoom_in</v-icon>  

</v-btn>

<UIDialog :dialog="dialog" @updateDialog="dialog = $event" />

<script>
  import UIDialog from '@/components/UI/UIDialog';
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        dialog: false
      }
    }
    components: {
      UIDialog
    }, 
    methods: {
      showDialog() {
         this.dialog = true;
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

This opens the dialog since I set dialog to `true`

**Child**

```
<v-dialog v-model="dialog" fullscreen scrollable>
  <v-card>
     This is a test
  </v-card>
</v-dialog>

<script>
 export default {
   props: {
     dialog: { type: Boolean, default: false }
   }, 
   watch: {
     dialog(val) {
       if (!val) this.$emit('updateDialog', false)
     }
   }
 }
</script>
```

I use watch since vue dialog doesn't have event. I managed to close the dialog but I'm still getting

```
Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders. Instead, use a data or computed property based on the prop's value
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to solve my problem by using computed property to get and set the dialog

**Child**

```
<v-dialog v-model="dialog" fullscreen scrollable>
  <v-card>
     This is a test
  </v-card>
</v-dialog>

<script>
 export default {
   props: {
     dialog: { type: Boolean, default: false }
   }, 
   computed: {
     dialogState: {
        get() { 
          return this.dialog;
        }, 
        set(val) {
          this.$emit('updateDialog', false);
        }
     }
   }
 }
</script>
```

Comment: Your issue was that you put `dialog` into `v-model` that means that you were changing its value despite it being a prop. Another solution for you would be to simply do: `:value="dialog"` instead of `v-model`

Comment: I don't understand where dialogState is being used? Is the dialog's v-model now supposed to point to computed dialogState instead of the dialog prop?

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

**Parent**

```
<app-my-dialog :dialog="doShowDialog" @close="doShowDialog = false"></app-my-dialog>
```

**Child component (app-my-dialog)**

```
<template>
  <v-dialog :value="showDialog" @click:outside="close()">
    <v-btn @click="close()">Close</v-btn>
  </v-dialog>
</template>
<script>
  export default {
    props: {
      dialog: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
     }
    }, 
    computed: {
      showDialog() {
        return this.dialog;
      }
    },
    methods: {
      close() {
        this.$emit('close')
      },
    }
  }
</script>
```

Note that if you use `<v-dialog :persistent="true" ...` (that means the dialog won't close on click outside itself), you can omit the `@click:outside="close()"`

Answer (score 0):

Decompose your v-model on UIDialog, in favor of

`<v-dialog v-bind:value="dialog" v-on:input="emitOutput">`

where `emitOutput` outputs a 'value' event

`emitOutput(value) {
      this.$emit('input', value)
    }`

-- This should handle the message of prop mutation in the console and also provide component level visibility control. You won't need to do any handling for custom events on the parent when emitting an 'input' event.

Answer (score 0):

Use `:value` and `@input` instead of declaring prop to `v-model`

Prop mutation error happens because `v-model` have already `:value` and its mutator, which is triggers this error. If you will use simple `:value` and declare for `@input` method `close()` it will work

Comment: can you give an example in code or a link? haven't seen this